# In C# why connection string is not exposed as an object?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Is there any particular reason, that I'm missing, for the connection string to be needed as a string, but not exposed as an object? I mean why should we always construct a string of this ugly form `'Data Source=MSSQL1;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=true'`, if we can set the exact same options up in an object exposed by some kind of dependency injection service. Or anything else that eliminates the need of us learning the keywords by heart.

Comment: [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: You could create a class with these properties that has a calculated connectionstring property.

Comment: Your reasoning is flawed.  Yes, that's a string, but there's also an object that represents connection strings.  It's called `SqlConnectionStringBuilder`.

Comment: @John, thank you very much. I wasn't aware of this object. This is exactly what I was thinking for.

Comment: ...and somewhere in a parallel universe: "These connection objects are just collections of strings.. why don't we json encode connection objects so they can be freely treated like strings?? :D"

Comment: You edited your question to complain about SqlConnectionStringBuilder being first included in .NET 4.7.2. That is incorrect, [it was in .NET 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder?view=netframework-2.0) which came out in 2006. Anyways, I've removed the mention of SqlConnectionStringBuilder from your question, because it feels more like it should be an answer, and Amy covered that nicely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question can be answered in two parts.

First, the reason connection settings are represented as strings is because they *generally* are set in configuration and don't change over the deployment of the application.  Once they're set, they're set and rarely, if ever, need to be changed.  So, a single string that represents the connection in configuration is generally all that's needed.  It's simple and straightforward.

Second, you can absolutely use an object to represent your connection settings using the `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` class.  You haven't heard of it because it's not used much, and it isn't used much because we rarely need to modify our connection settings at runtime.  The only time I've used `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` was when I wanted to *parse* a connection string to log it without sensitive bits like the password.

Comment: Totally understood your point and agree. But also it's very nice to hear about the SqlConnectionStringBuilder option, because although I may use it only once in my project's code base, it will also allow me to concentrate on more meaningful tasks than to try to recall this string's spelling.

Answer (score 5):

**TL; DR:** The main reason is that connection strings should be located in a **config file**. This means that the data needs to conform to the format of the config file. A simple string (as opposed to a collection of properties) works for every type of config file and requires no format-specific syntax for e.g. a JSON or XML config file.

---

Secondly, not every connectionstring uses the exact same properties. Some properties are mutually exclusive (e.g. integrated security versus login credentials), some properties are have different names for different data providers.

[Connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/) is a good example of how varied connectionstrings can be. You'll see that not every property is used in every string.

> **Update** - [This is a list of connection string properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/instances/connection-string-properties-analysis-services?view=sql-server-2017) for specifically connecting to Analysis Services. This doesn't even factor in other data providers, and look how complex the collection of properties already is.

If you were to make an object to represent your connectionstring, you would have to expose *all possible* properties, which is more than the average developer will have need for, thus causing a lot of redundant (and empty) settings.

Thirdly, you often don't just change *one* of the settings of a connectionstring. Connectionstrings are considered as a whole, because after they have been created, you basically work with "the DEV connectionstring" or "the TEST connectionstring".
To that end, it's often safer to simply think of the connectionstrings as whole objects instead of collection of properties.

Lastly, if you really want to define your connectionstring by its separate properties, you can still do that. [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder?view=netframework-4.7.2) exists for that very purpose.

But most developers don't construct their own connectionstrings and instead use them as a config key, for the reason I mentioned above.

Comment: 1. Can't you pass a JsonWriter/XmlWriter parameter to your ToString method of the object? DI, 2. Base abstract class and a set of subclasses for each meaningful scenario? Polymorphism, 3. Encapsulation? 4. Works great for me. Thank you.

Comment: @GeorgiVatsov: (1) You're inverting the operation here. The code doesn't write the config values, it **reads** it. Furthermore, the database code should not care about which type of config file is used; you want to be able to use this database projects in different top-level projects (all of which can have different config approaches) (2) It's still a complicated system with no meaningful benefits, given that connectionstrings, once created, are often treated as immutable string values (3) What about encapsulation? (4) You're welcome.

Comment: 1. If the default behavior is to write a string, but you also have other options, you basically just give more simpler options to your users. 2. I may use this "complicated system" only once in an app, but still I'd use it on all my apps. I'd like to see a code that have used all of the objects in all of the DLLs at least once. Then I'd change my mind if this is no "meaningful benefit". 3. You use it to modify how the method's user may interact with your object. In other words, if you don't want your users to change only one property, you don't allow them to.

Comment: @GeorgiVatsov: 1. You seem to misunderstand the purpose of a config file. The config file is, as far as the deployed application is concerned, a collection of immutable settings that the developers (but not the end-users) have access to. The application should not be setting its own config file. The purpose of the config file that it is an **unquestionable source of key information**. The end users should not be choosing the connectionstring. At best, they can choose from a list of options, where each option is already predefined in the config file.

Comment: @GeorgiVatsov: 2. You're putting the cart before the horse. It's not being done because there's no point to doing so. It's counterintuitive to want to see a real life example of something that people don't do because it doesn't benefit them. The complexity of implementing your "all properties available" solution matches the complexity required to compose the connectionstring in the first place, so you haven't actually simplified anything.

Comment: @GeorgiVatsov: 3. A connectionstring should **never** _"modify how the method's user may interact with your object"_. The logical flow of your application remains unchanged regardless of which connectionstring you're using. That's exactly why it's put in a config file, because it doesn't matter to the actual business logic. You should not be setting business rules via the connectionstring. The connectionstring is a _technical_ implementation detail.

Comment: 1. I know what config file is and I want my SqlConnectionStringBuilder to write there. Exactly how it does. 2. There is obviously a class to do job I wanted to, so it is not the "cart before the horse" case. 3. Yes. The connection string should "never" do this, but the encapsulation is meant to do just that.

Comment: @GeorgiVatsov: If you want a _different_ application to generate a config file for you, that's fine. But having your application generate its own config file defeats the purpose of the config file, as that means you've either hardcoded the default values, or you're relying on user input to generate the config values.

Comment: It's not an application. It's a class. And this class is SqlConnectionStringBuilder.

Comment: @GeorgiVatsov: A config file is an application-level setting. This is why I mention that it seems like you misunderstand the purpose of the config file. Even if you have an SqlConnectionStringBuilder, where does the builder get its values (the server address, the database name, ...) from? Either they're hardcoded (bad practice), entered by the user at runtime (bad practice unless the application is a DB management tool like SSMS), or **from the config file** (good practice). Whether you store the information as separate values or a composed connectionstring, you should use a config file.

Answer (score 1):

IMO the most important reason is to encourage developers to store the *entire* connection string as a configuration parameter.

This enables you to change any part of the connection string you want without rebuilding and redeploying the application.

If you choose to have configuration parameters to set only individual connection string parameters, like server name and database name, then you can't connect to a named instance, set read-only intent, adjust the connection pool parameters, etc, without changing the source code.

Probably the historical reason for this is that connection strings vary by ADO.NET provider, and ADO.NET is designed to enable provider-agnostic code.  Since .NET 2.0 you can even code end-to-end applications that have no compile-time dependency on a particular ADO.NET provider. See [ADO.NET Facory Model Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/factory-model-overview)